# Box API bad request when uploading image

Tags: qt, api, post, box-api, box

According to box API to upload a file this is the curl command:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
      -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
      -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

I am trying to upload an image using QT, the following is my code:

```
QUrl url(QString::fromLatin1("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"));
    auto* multipart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    QHttpPart attributes;
    attributes.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                    QLatin1String("form-data; name=\"attributes\""));
    QByteArray postData = QString::fromUtf8("{\"name\":\"%1\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"%2\"}}").arg(QFileInfo(imgPath).fileName()).arg(id).toUtf8();
    attributes.setBody(postData);
    multipart->append(attributes);

    QFile* file = new QFile(imgPath);
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    file->setParent(multipart);

    QHttpPart imagepart;
    imagepart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));
    imagepart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,QVariant(QString::fromLatin1("form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"%1\"").arg(QLatin1String(QFileInfo(imgPath).fileName().toUtf8()))));
    imagepart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, file->size());    
    imagepart.setBodyDevice(file);
    multipart->append(imagepart);

    QNetworkRequest netRequest(url);
    netRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QLatin1String("multipart/form-data"));
    netRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", QString::fromLatin1("Bearer {%1}").arg(d->o2->token()).toUtf8());
    d->reply = d->netMngr->post(netRequest, multipart);
    multipart->setParent(d->reply);
```

When I try to upload the image I get an error saying

> Error transferring https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content -
>   server replied: Bad Request

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The content length header in the image part seems unnecessary at least, have you tried without it?

Comment: Yes I tried first without it

Comment: Ok, what I would suggest then is to send both the Qt and the curl request to a local domain (e.g. via "nc -l 8080") where you can print both requests and check the difference... does this reveal more insight?

Comment: I think that this is a good idea, I can actually view the request from curl using --trace..but how can i do that from qt? I am sorry i have never dealt with nc before

Comment: nc or netcat with the "-l" options listens on a specific port and will just print everything it gets on the console; it exists for Linux, Windows and others. So if you let netcat listen on port 8080 via "nc -l 8080" you could issue both your Qt and your curl request to "http://localhost:8080" and then see how the two requests differ...